# deselect a group of rows by their rowname

Tags: r

I would like deselect a group of rows by their rowname

```
A <- data.frame(c("a","b","c"),c("d","e","f"))
rownames(A) <- c("RA","RB","RC")
```

but

```
A[-"RA",]
```

gives error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `setdiff`.

Your data (with nicer column names):

```
> A <- data.frame(V1 = c("a","b","c"), V2 = c("d","e","f"))
> rownames(A) <- c("RA","RB","RC")
> A
   V1 V2
RA  a  d
RB  b  e
RC  c  f
```

What you've tried, and the resulting error:

```
> A[-"RA",]
Error in -"RA" : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Making use of `setdiff`:

```
> A[setdiff(rownames(A), "RA"), ]
   V1 V2
RB  b  e
RC  c  f
```

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` provides syntax that's very close to what you're looking for. Instead of having row names, create a column (I called it "info" in the example below) and set that column to be the key. Then you can do the following:

```
library(data.table)
A = data.table(c("a","b","c"), c("d","e","f"), info=c("RA","RB","RC"),
               key = "info")
#   V1 V2 info
#1:  a  d   RA
#2:  b  e   RB
#3:  c  f   RC

A["RA"]
#   info V1 V2
#1:   RA  a  d

A[!"RA"]
#   V1 V2 info
#1:  b  e   RB
#2:  c  f   RC
```

Comment: You can also use `keep.rownames=TRUE` to create a column called `rn` from the rownames of a data.frame.